# testing super and sub classes with one test class

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I have **two** custom Date **classes** (let's call them `DateV1` and `DateV2`), **one being the super and the other the sub**, both implementing exactly the same methods.
Starting from JUnit 4.x, parameterized tests seem to offer **a way to test both classes within a single test class** (although some people seem to find parameterized tests confusing and generally steer clear of them).

Because I'm new to `JUnit` (and, indeed, `Java`) and have been writing nothing but the simplest of tests, I'd like to hear from more proficient `JUnit` users **how to tackle situations like these**.
I've been going over the theory in *JUnit In Action, 2nd Ed., Manning, July 2010* but I'm having difficulties seeing how this would be used in a super/sub scenario.

It won't come as a surprise that I'm not including code because frankly I don't have any at the moment. I'm not asking for *microwave code*, but some pointers would be appreciated so I can be on my merry way and not write a bunch of boilerplate.

Comment: I can think of plenty of clunky ways to do  this but nothing elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have such `DateV1` and `DateV2`:

```
public class DateV1 {

    protected final Date date;

    public DateV1(Date date) { 
        this.date = date;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return 1900 + date.getYear();
    }
}

public class DateV2 extends DateV1 {

    private Calendar cal;

    public DateV2(Date date) {
        super(date);
        cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);      
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }
}
```

The test might look like:

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class DateTest {

    private DateV1 date;

    public DateTest(DateV1 date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Collection<Object[]> data() {
        final Date currDate = new Date();
        Object[][] data = new Object[][] { { new DateV1(currDate) }, { new DateV2(currDate) } };
        return Arrays.asList(data);
    }

    @Test
    public void getYearShouldReturn2013() {
        Assert.assertEquals(2013, date.getYear());
    }
}
```

However, there is one important question: Should your super and sub classes (`DateV1` and `DateV2`) be tested in exactly the same way? Does the `DateV2` class deliver **exactly** the same functionality as its superclass `DateV1`? If there is absolutely no difference in behavior between these classes why have the two? If there is a difference between the two then it should be addressed by your test.

Comment: in short: `DateV1` is written from scratch, using a "best effort" principle, `DateV2` makes use of `java.util.GregorianCalendar`. The number of methods, their signatures and return types are identical. So yes, I would say the tests should be identical.